# Inserting Sequence of Numbers to Text Range with Criteria

Tags: excel, text, sequence

In Excel 2010, I have a list of Cities in Column A, list of Communities in Column B, and unique user-assigned codes for each Community in Column C.

Because these codes are non-sequential (1011N, 1032B, etc) and have no logic to them, I wish to produce in Column D my own simple coding system, like this:

CityCommunity01
CityCommunity02
CityCommunity03
....
CityCommunity50

The challenge I am having is, I have had to essentially use three formulas.

The first one creates CityCommunity01.

The second formula (from the second item to the 9th) looks at the row above, finds the 01, and adds 1.

The third formula looks at the 9th item and adds 1 again, this time without appending the "0" in order to avoid 011, 012, etc.

Is there a way to do this with just one formula? (I have found other similar solutions, but have either required add-ins or VBA, neither of which should be necessary. This could probably be done with multiple nested IFS, but I'm sure there is a more elegant approach).

**Update:** Count must restart for each new Community.

Comment: Update your request if count must restart for each city

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about the following in Column D (starting in D1):

```
=A1&B1&IF(COUNTIFS($A$1:A1,A1,$B$1:B1,B1)<10,"0","")&COUNTIFS($A$1:A1,A1,$B$1:B1,B1)
```

Comment: This is very, very close! If I want to take this one step further: let's assume your formula will go in Column E starting in E1. In Column D, I have two subtypes: X, and Y. Your formula indeed resets the count for each new community in Column C, but if I wanted to make it reset again if the subtype changes from X to Y, what modification do we need to make?

Comment: Update: I updated the formula to simply add another criteria in order to do the above. It worked, even with noncontiguous lists (and it remembers where it left off last!). I would upvote your answer, but I currently have insufficient privileges.

Comment: You can accept my answer as the answer to your original question. That would be big help for others looking for something similar.